# Pandoc Lua : how to add a markdown block around a header without losing the markdown syntax #

Tags: lua, pandoc

I am trying to add a div around a markdown header in a Lua filter, but the # in front of the title disappear in the output.

```
Header = function(el)
    if el.level == 1 then
        local content = el.content
        local pre = pandoc.RawBlock('markdown','::: test')
        local post = pandoc.RawBlock('markdown',':::')
        table.insert(content,1,pre)
        table.insert(content, post)
        return content
    else
        return el
    end
end
```

Input:

```
# Linux
## Support for Linux users
Create a shell script
```

Expected Output

```
::: test
# Linux
:::
## Support for Linux users
Create a shell script
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `content` field contains the heading text, but the heading itself is the `el` element that's not returned. Returning it together with the raw blocks should work though:

```lua
return {
  pre, el, post
}
```

Or use a Div element:

```lua
function Header (el)
  if h.level == 1 then
    return pandoc.Div(el, {class = 'test'})
  end
end
```